# How to fix specs failing because of multicore testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, jenkins

I run specs for an Rails-App with RSpec on Jenkins server. And i get some wired failings:

```
invoices = Invoice.find_all_by_user_id(@seller.id)
invoices.should_not be_nil
invoice = invoices.last
invoice.generated_at.should be_close(Time.now.utc, 3)

# error in jenkins
undefined method `generated_at' for nil:NilClass
```

In the before(:each) the @seller is reset and new created. If two or more of the specs running at the same time, it will reset die @seller in between.

So what is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Each process needs to run its specs in its own database. You need to create a number of databases (`app_test_1`, `app_test_2`, etc) and configure your tests to run in them.

How are you running your tests in parallel? parallel_test? specjour? hydra?

Answer (score 0):

Use different databases for each process. It can be achieved by using this gem: https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests .